# Localized / translated paths in Lektor

Tags: python, path, localization, internationalization, lektor

The [Lektor docs clearly state](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/content/paths/#alternatives-and-paths):

> If you have a page that exists in both German and English alternative then they will have the same path.

If you need localized paths, what would be the easiest / best way to get them? Anything better than solving it on the webserver level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to overwrite the slug per content file with the `_slug` field ([source](https://www.getlektor.com/docs/content/system-fields/#_slug)).

Say you have a contact page on an english site with german translation. You would probably have an english `contact/contents.lr`. Just add the following line to `contact/contents+de.lr`:

```
_slug: kontakt
```